# Avoiding duplicate rows via redisson

Tags: mysql, redis, duplicates, redisson, distributed-lock

I do have a table, Foo. I add rows to this table on certain events. The current overall design is such that duplicate messages cannot be avoided. This results in adding of duplicate rows to the table.

I cannot put a unique constraint on the table as there are different type of messages that become rows in this table. I want to avoid duplicate only for specific type of message.

Since the duplicate messages often come concurrently, and that application runs on multiple nodes, i decided to use radisson to take a distributed lock. However it does not seem to be working. I am still getting duplicate rows in the table.

Duplicate messages are detected based on userId, date and type. Below is the minimalistic demo code. I am trying to do a read before the write and this read is happening in a synchronized block across application nodes.

Appreciate any inputs on this.

```
     if(updateEntry.getType().equals(Type.XYZ) {
       java.sql.Date date = updateEntry.getDate();
       String redisLockKey = "MyAPP" + "-" + userId+"-"+date.toString()+ "-" + "type-XYZ";
       RLock rLock =    redissonClient.getLock(redisLockKey);
       rLock.lock(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       MyEntity myEntity = myEntityRepository.findByUserIdAndDateAndActivityType(userId,date,Type.XYZ);
       if(null == myEntity) {
           myEntity = new MyEntity();
           // myEntity setters
        myEntity = myEntityRepository.saveAndFlush(myEntity);
       }
       rLock.unlock();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The above code block was inside @Transactional. With spring default isolation level, it was REPEATABLE_READ at mysql. Taking the lock outside the transaction fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyEntity myEntity = myEntityRepository.findByUserIdAndDateAndActivityType(userId,date,Type.XYZ);
if(null == myEntity) {
   myEntity = new MyEntity();
   // myEntity setters
   myEntity = myEntityRepository.saveAndFlush(myEntity);
}
```

According to this part of code, you are treating userId, date, and type as unique criteria to decide if you can insert this record. So can you explain why you cannot make them three together as a combined unique constraints.